# How to parse dateTime format for an edit text in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am consuming a dot net web service in android by the method SOAP.

That web service is having the input values in the form of `DateTime` format,so getting this issue on my project

```
"java.lang.NumberFormatException. unable to parse 01/01/2012 as integer"
```

Can anyone tell me, how to parse datetime format in android

Answer (score 1):

To parse Date from 01/01/2012, you should use SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat smf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
long time=smf.parse(dateField.getText().toString()).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SimpleDateFormat dfDate_m  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = dfDate_m.parse(str);
```

click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more clarification